# requests doesn't get the full body content

Tags: html, python-3.x, python-requests

I know, this is the question that have been already asked much. So I tried some solutions, and it worked for my other works.

But this site is different, I think.
I tried this at first.

```
html = requests.get(url = "http://loawa.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content.decode('utf-8','replace'), 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

It fetches me a head, and slight of body.

```
<body class="p-0 bg-theme-6" style="overflow-x:hidden"><script>window.location.reload(true);</script></body>
```

So I used prerender as

```
html = requests.get(url = "http://service.prerender.io/http://loawa.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content.decode('utf-8','replace'), 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

It gives me the same result.
So I tried it with headers.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36','Content-Type': 'text/html',}
response = requests.get("http://loawa.com",headers=headers)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content.decode('utf-8','replace'), 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

The html comes out as empty. Not sure I did a right job with headers.
What can I try more with? I don't want to use selenium for this work.
Hope someone can enlighten me. Thanks!

Comment: The first thing that you tried is giving me the complete response, can you please tell which version of python and beautifulsoup are you using

Comment: @AlokRaj Hi!, that's strange. Actually it worked about 2 months ago. I thought page owner changed something but, since you said it, it might be the issue with me.

I'm using Python 3.6 with Spyder and beautifulsoup4 - 4.8.1

Comment: Can you try creating a virtual python environment and upgrading python to python 3.9.5. It will work fine

Comment: @AlokRaj I'll try it, but would there be a lot of works if want to run it on AWS? I mean, setting python environment there?

Comment: I would suggest to use local, it's easier there and not that much confusing also

Comment: Let me know if you want me to share the command with you. I can write and share it

Comment: @AlokRaj Thanks for the offer. But I got a bigger issue now. Actually those codes were supposed to be used in my Discord bot. I reinstalled Anaconda3, and then whole bot code stopped running haha... I hope this is just my laptop's problem. I'm gonna try with my desktop and see how it would go.

Comment: Sure nps, let me know if you face any issue. Will be happy to help :)